# PHP set TimeZone without changing date?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I send UNIX timestamp from javascript `vat stamp = +new Date/1000` to PHP.

Then I do

```
//Here $d = '2015/04/03 00:00:00'
$d = new DateTime("@{$stamp}");
$d->setTimezone( new DateTimeZone( 'Pacific/Auckland' ) );

//Here $d = '2015/04/03 00:00:00' + 7:15 hrs ( 7:15 hrs is time diff between my browser & Auckland)
```

I want to change the timezone but keep the date to same. So, after I `setTimezone` to `Pacific/Auckland`, the date should still be `'2015/04/03 00:00:00'`.

Comment: Take the timestamp coming into php and store it as a variable, and the convert the present date in the different timezone and compare the two and adjust + or - from there

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I need to point out that you're asking for something nonsensical. A UNIX timestamp represents an *absolute point in time*. It does not represent "2015/04/03 00:00:00", because that *date format* can refer to a few dozen different points in time, depending on which timezone you're interpreting this string in. A UNIX timestamp doesn't have this problem, what point in time it represents is not negotiable based on timezones.

If you take an absolute point in time and want to format it as a human readable time which depends on timezones, then this human readable value *will* necessarily change by applying a different timezone to it. What you're asking for is to change the point in time the timestamp refers to, at which point it's just arbitrary.

Comment: To give context to op's question, since I have same need. In my case, I have a database where time is stored with Europe/Paris timezone but is considered as UTC time upon retrieval... So I needed to set timezone without changing time in this special case until I get to fix all dates in database.

For now @Henry's answer worked well.

Comment: @Herz3h How exactly do you store a *UNIX timestamp* as "Europe/Paris"?!

Comment: Wrong wording I guess, what I mean is that the DateTime object that will be used to store the date in db has wrong timezone in first place, and it gets stored in database just as if it has utc timezone.

Comment: *"has wrong timezone in first place"* — Aha, that makes more sense and is really a different problem…

Answer (score 37):

Here's one way to do it.

```
$_date = new \DateTime($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), new \DateTimeZone('<time zone>'));
```